# JSON Formating on web pages

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

I am fetching json data from a server that returns `JSON` that looks this:

```
{
    blogbody: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque omnis veniam optio distinctio eligendi doloremque.↵↵Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque omnis veniam optio distinctio eligendi doloremque.↵↵Below is a list - Lorem ipsum dolor sit:↵ ⁃ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.↵ ⁃ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.↵ ⁃ An experience section.↵ ⁃ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (if any).↵ ⁃ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. ↵↵Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. ↵↵Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!↵",
    blogimage: "https://source.unsplash.com/it",
    blogtype: "code",
    blogvideo: "",
    description: "Some description ",
    links: [el, el, el],
    posted: "2020-08-24T07:33:10.693Z",
    title: "Some title",
    __v: 0,
    _id: "5f436d367341110004f4nsbsjb2"
}
```

How can I format the `blogbody` value on a webpage to create a p tag for every sentence before and enter key and a ul tag for every list? Please assist.

Comment: It would be better if you include details about what you have tried so far to achieve it. Which provide little more insights about the question to others

Comment: If you want full control you should work with template literals. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/5wx1husj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break the sentence into an array by using the `.split(".")` this is essentially going to give you something like this:

```
["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elite", "another sentence"]
```

Then you can loop through this array with any of the methods on the `Array.prototype` such as `forEach`, `map`, etc and create and append your `p` element to the DOM.

So you're going to end up writing something along the lines of :

```
const data = {
    blogbody: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque omnis veniam optio distinctio eligendi doloremque.↵↵Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque omnis veniam optio distinctio eligendi doloremque.↵↵Below is a list - Lorem ipsum dolor sit:↵ ⁃ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.↵ ⁃ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.↵ ⁃ An experience section.↵ ⁃ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (if any).↵ ⁃ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. ↵↵Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. ↵↵Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!↵",
    blogimage: "https://source.unsplash.com/it",
    blogtype: "code",
    blogvideo: "",
    description: "Some description ",
    links: ["el", "el", "el"],
    posted: "2020-08-24T07:33:10.693Z",
    title: "Some title",
    __v: 0,
    _id: "5f436d367341110004f4nsbsjb2"
}

const sentences = data.blogbody.split(".")
const div = document.createElement("div")
const ps = sentences.map(s => `<p>${s}</p>`)
div.innerHTML = ps.join("")
```

Then you may try to figure out how to strip the `enter` too from the sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should add one inner array for UL list within blogbody value and for ENTER,
add `<BR>` tag before sending JSON data to the code.